# Setting an empty string to null on Insert into database

Tags: c#, .net, string, sql-insert, dbnull

I haven't been able to find the right solution for this issue, and I know it's so simple but I have forgotten how to do it. I have a form with one textfield field that is not required by the user to fill in. I want to insert NULL into the database, not a 0 which is it currently doing. I am not sure what I am missing, though. The textbox is named `taxRateTxt`, and what I have currently does not work for me:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
    {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FIPSCountyCode", countyCodeTxt.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StateCode", stateCodeList.SelectedValue));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CountyName", countyNameTxt.Text));

        string taxStr = taxRateTxt.Text;
        //test for an empty string and set it to db null
        if (taxStr == String.Empty)
        {
            taxStr = DBNull.Value;

        }

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TaxRate", taxStr));

        if (AddBtn.Visible == true)

            cmd.CommandText = addQuery;

        if (EditBtn.Visible == true)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = editQuery;
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have a default value for the column?

Comment: Your statement `taxStr = DBNull.Value;` should give you a compile time error.

Comment: if you need to insert null ,just omit that field from you Insert SQL Script(if there is no default value for that field).Can you add your insert script to the post?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove this block of code

```
string taxStr = taxRateTxt.Text;
//test for an empty string and set it to db null
if (taxStr == String.Empty)
{
    taxStr = DBNull.Value;

}
```

and change this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TaxRate", taxStr));
```

to this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TaxRate", string.IsNullOrEmpty(taxRateTxt.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : taxRateTxt.Text));
```

Comment: Love the casting `DBNull.Value` to `object` trick.  Saves so much time -)

Answer (score 4):

Passing in `Convert.DBNull` (or `DBNull.Value`) will do it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx

Of course, you'll have to check the string value first and then pass that in instead.